# Why do I get a 404 Error when attempting to get an access_token from google OAuth 2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

I'm currently building a OAuth authorization to get email and profile info only.

I can get the code easy using the following:

```
def authorize
  base = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"
  params = {
    :scope => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback/",
    :client_id => "id",
    :response_type => 'code'
  }
  redirect_to base + params.to_query
end
```

However, when I try to get the access token from Google, I get a 404 error:

```
def callback
  code = params[:code]
  client_id = 'id'
  client_secret = 'secret'
  redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback/"
  http = Net::HTTP.new('accounts.google.com', 80)
  path = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?"
  headers = {'Content-Type'=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
  parameters = "code=#{code}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=#{client_secret}&client_id=#{client_id}&redirect_uri=#{redirect_uri}"
  resp, data = http.post(path,parameters,headers)
end

response code: 404  data: Google Home | Sign in

The page you requested is invalid.
```

I'm not entirely sure what the issue might be. I've tried to match with copy+paste the registered callback URL. I've checked my parameters multiple times and I cannot find what could be causing the error.

I'm following the [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#handlingtheresponse) and registered with Google with the following information:

```
Client ID for web applications 
Client ID: id
Client secret: secret
Redirect URIs: http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback/ 
JavaScript origins: none
```

Comment: Are they doing any redirects? Net::HTTP doesn't handle them automatically like Open-URI will, but Open-URI doesn't support POST. You might look at Typhoeus, which handles both very nicely.

Comment: As per google's documentation, it's suposed to return a json blob with either the access token or an error. There should be no redirects for this call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working!

Seems like i was missing a couple of things:

1. Added the SSL settings for the HTTP request.
2. Send the parameters as the body and not as part of the request.
3. Put the content-type in the request correctly.

I hope this helps someone out there!

```
param = {
  :code => params[:code],
  :client_id => client_id,
  :client_secret => client_secret,
  :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback/",
  :grant_type => 'authorization_code'
}

uri = URI.parse("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.body = param.to_query
response = http.request(request)
```

Comment: FYI, I had to hardcode the port to 443 because uri.port was returning 80 (Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.0.9)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get Google to redirect to:

```
:redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback/",
```

I suspect they can't find `localhost`. Give them your real IP number.

Comment: I believe this not an issue. The initial call to get the token works correctly. They return to my localhost machine and it's even on their form to sign the application. I will try to deploy to heroku and experiment over there.